# How to calculate the energy in thermoelastic damping?

Tags: thermodynamics, elasticity

*Note - I'm not 100% sure *thermoelastic damping* is the right term here - so please feel free to correct the question in case I'm wrong!*

If a force is applied to an elastic rod such that it elastically bends the rod, there is some amount of heat energy created in the rod due to this bending. If the rod is released from it's displaced state it would swing back to it's original state and then over swing by some value, this oscillation would quickly damp to 0 and there would be a static rod remaining.

Now the #1 rule when it comes to energy lost is it's always heat - so clearly the energy from this rod is lost through heating (in fact if I repeatedly stretch an elastic band it heats - this is probably related). Is there a simple equation (or set of equations) that can be used to calculate the energy that is taken from the system as heat?